# Formatting SharePoint columns to display button with JSON

Tags: json, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint library with a status field and a button field. The button field has formatted JSON code to execute a Flow but the button only displays if the Status field is set to a certain value. This works great. However, I would the button to display if the Status field is value 1 OR value 2. How do I do that in the code? Thanks!!

````
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Archive Machine",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"88258048-da4b-101c-8b4a-e91ebd385d5e\"}"
  },
  "style": {
    "background-color": "purple",
    "color": "white",
    "visibility": {
      "operator": "?",
      "operands": [
        {
          "operator": "==",
          "operands": [
            "[$Status]",
            "Status1"
          ]
        },
        "visible",
        "hidden"
      ]
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Do you have any further questions? Please remember to accept the helpful answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the steps:**

1.Create a Choice column named [Status]

[image]

2.Use the below JSON code to Formate [Status] column

```
{
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
 "elmType": "button",
 "txtContent": "Archive Machin",
 "customRowAction": {
   "action": "executeFlow",
   "actionParams": "{\"id\":\"88258048-da4b-101c-8b4a-e91ebd385d5e\"}"
 },
 "style": {
   "background-color": "purple",
   "color": "white",
   "visibility": "=if(([$Status] == '1') || ([$Status] == '2'),'visible','hidden')"
}
}
```

[image]